# Android programmatic table fill cells

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm trying to programmatically fill a TableLayout with buttons. However I want them to fill the entire available space.

But the Buttons are not using the entireheight they could, and their margins are ignored. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbAjA.png).

How can I force them to fill all the available space, and have some margin beween them? The result should be basically a grid of buttons with some margin between them, but stretching the entire screen.

Heres my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TableLayout myTable = findViewById(R.id.myTable);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowLayoutParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

        int counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowLayoutParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Button b = new Button(this, null, R.attr.myButtonStyle);
                b.setText("Button " + counter);
                tableRow.addView(b, j);

                counter++;
            }

            myTable.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myTable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    tools:context="com.example.tabletest.MainActivity">

</TableLayout>
```

And the button style which is referenced via the attrs:

```
<style name="myButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">fill</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">45sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Your children of TableLayout are of type TableRow. The layout_height of a TableRow is always WRAP_CONTENT. They'll never be taller than the buttons are. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html

Comment: Hopefully this is clearer. If you set the height of your buttons to a evenly divide up the screen, they'll fill the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get this to work like that either.

However a workaround for this would be replacing the `TableLayout` with a vertical `LinearLayout` and then replacing the `TableRow` with another `LinearLayout`, this time horizontal. Then set the Buttons to `layout_width = 0` and `layout_weight = 1`. (Also add margins if necessary)

You should then have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout myTable = findViewById(R.id.myTable);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tableRowLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams tableBtnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
        int tableBtnMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        tableBtnParams.setMargins(tableBtnMargin,tableBtnMargin,tableBtnMargin,tableBtnMargin);

        int counter = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            LinearLayout tableRow = new LinearLayout(this);
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(tableRowLayoutParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Button b = new Button(this, null, R.attr.myButtonStyle);
                b.setLayoutParams(tableBtnParams);
                b.setText("Button " + counter);
                tableRow.addView(b, j);

                counter++;
            }

            myTable.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Final Product]